# Encounter error when creating a new Phoenix/Elixir project

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, phoenix-live-view

Following the standard procedure to create a new Phoenix/Elixir project. However, encounter error during installation. Please comment how to solve this error.

**0. Setting**

```
$ node -v
v14.18.1

$ npm -v
6.14.15

$ elixir -v
Erlang/OTP 24 [erts-12.1.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [jit] [dtrace]
Elixir 1.12.3 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 24)

$ mix phx.new --version
Phoenix installer v1.6.2
```

**1. Create a folder to persist the DB data.**

```
mkdir ${HOME}/phoenix-postgres-data/
```

**2. Run a Docker container with the Postgres image.**

```
$ docker run -d \
 --name phoenix-psql \
 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Phoenix1234 \
 -v ${HOME}/phoenix-postgres-data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
 -p 5432:5432 \
 postgres
```

**3. Validate that the container is running.**

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE      COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
fca9fbc140e6   postgres   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 hours ago   Up 6 minutes   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   phoenix-psql
```

**4. Creating a New Project**

```
$ mix phx.new pento --live
* creating pento/config/config.exs
* creating pento/config/dev.exs
* creating pento/config/prod.exs
* creating pento/config/runtime.exs
...
* creating pento/priv/static/favicon.ico

Fetch and install dependencies? [Yn] Y
* running mix deps.get
* running mix deps.compile
```

**5. Finishing touch**

```
$ cd pento
$ mix ecto.create && mix phx.server && iex -S mix phx.server
```

**Error Message**

```
Compiling 14 files (.ex)
Generated pento app

18:47:31.378 [error] GenServer #PID<0.411.0> terminating
** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 28P01 (invalid_password) password authentication failed for user "postgres"
    (db_connection 2.4.0) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:100: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection 1.1.0) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib 3.16.1) proc_lib.erl:226: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: Postgrex.Protocol

18:47:31.423 [error] GenServer #PID<0.419.0> terminating
** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 28P01 (invalid_password) password authentication failed for user "postgres"
    (db_connection 2.4.0) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:100: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection 1.1.0) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib 3.16.1) proc_lib.erl:226: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: Postgrex.Protocol
** (Mix) The database for Pento.Repo couldn't be created: killed
```

Comment: Did you update the `config/dev.exs` (and others?) with the proper database credentials?  Are you able to log into the database independently e.g. using psql CLI or PSequel?

Answer (score 3):

The database must be configured for [ecto](/questions/tagged/ecto). Make sure you have something like the lines below in your `config/config.exs`

```elixir
config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: "postgres",
  password: "Phoenix1234",
  database: "my_app_dev",
  hostname: "localhost",
  pool_size: 10
```

or. alternatively, set the password in docker postgres to be empty.